# Javascript How pass this Keyword to a Function?

Tags: javascript, properties, this, element

Hi every one I would like to modify an a Property from a button ease right jajaja

`document.getElementById("button_1").style.visibility = "collapse";`

But here I have the id from the object I would like to alter but if i don't know specifically the id because the object's come from a loop I should use "this" the JavaScript Keyword right? like "this.id" to get in to the id of the object it call's example

`<input type='button' id='button_1' onclick='alert(this.id)' >Click Me!</button>`

That will show the id from that element

When I call a Function

```
<script>
function Funtion_Alert() {

    alert (this.id);

}
</script>

<input type='button' id='button_1' onclick='Funtion_Alert(this)' >Click Me!</button>
```

I get in y the alert undefined I need get the id from the element which is being calling the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you pass `this`. `this` is special, it's a context of your current function invocation.

*Either* pass it as an argument, but then you have to call it something else inside the function, like here:

```html
<script>
function Funtion_Alert(element) { // <<< note the argument!

    alert(element.id); // <<< note the different name!

}
</script>

<input type='button' id='button_1' onclick='Funtion_Alert(this)' >Click Me!</button>
```

...*or* pass it as actual `this`, by using [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```html
<script>
function Funtion_Alert() {

    alert(this.id);

}
</script>

<input type='button' id='button_1' onclick='Funtion_Alert.call(this)' >Click Me!</button>
<!-- note the .call -->
```

Otherwise, the `this` inside the function will be `window` [as explained here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), so `this.id` will essentially be `window.id` which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You're also starting an `input` tag and then closing with a `button`.

A more idiomatic way of achieving what you're looking for is to [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the element:

```js
let button = document.getElementById("button_1");
button.addEventListener("click", (e) => alert(e.target.id));
```

```html
<button id="button_1">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are starting the tag with input field and ending with `</button>`.

Use this instead, It will work :-)

```html
<button type='button' id='button_1' onclick='alert(this.id)' >Click Me!</button>
```

**Edit (ater your comment):** By the way as much as I could have understood you problem for that the syntax `this.id` already return a string which you can directly use as `document.getElementById(obj.id)`, the obj (an object) can be passed from button like this...

```js
function foo(obj){
  txt = document.getElementById(obj.id).textContent;
  alert(txt);
}
```

```html
<button id="my_id" onclick="foo(this)">Click Me!!</button>
```

Sorry for late reply :-)

Comment: oh yes I see thanks but I wrote that here for example isn't the code on the website :)

Comment: If you can provide me the code which you used for your website I may help you there too ...